# what is the difference between editable = "top" and editable = "bottom" in odoo 10?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

here is my code,

```
<tree string="School Tree" editable="top">
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="school_id"/>
    <field name="age" />
</tree>
```

I tried with both **editable="top"** and **editable="bottom"** but it gives same result, can anyone explain the exact difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can see the difference in x2many field:

`editable="top"` when you click on add item a row is added to the top of the tree to enter the  information

`editable="bottom"` the row is added to the bottom.

In one2many or many2many use bottom or you will confuse the user when the row is added to the top of the tree specialy when there are tens a of lines.